# Selenium 2 Webdriver test as service called using REST

Tags: java, rest, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to understand where I need to look to implement such scenario:
What I have:
1. I have variety of testing scenarios implemented on Java with Selenium 2 Webdriver.
2. I'm running my test scenarios (suits) using TestNG (defined list of classes and methods in order in xml file), building using Maven.
3. All on my local machine and from my local machine

What I need:
1. I need to implement ability to call my test suites from external test framework. As result of this call - test execution should be started.
2. I need to send parameters to my Tests, so call should contain parameters that should be passed to my code.
3. I need to send "a message" to external framework when tests would be done (with info : success of failed)

I'm thinking to implement this collaboration between two frameworks using REST

My questions:
1. How architecture should look like? Should I run any server so my service would be available 24/7 for external framework? How to write such service?
2. Where to read about it?
3. Any examples of classes/methods that should be implemented to send parameters/ to get parameters?

thank you in advance for any ideas.

Comment: Found few info here http://rest.elkstein.org

Comment: OK, As far as I see Selenium GRID2 should be that server on which my service should be running https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/Grid2

Comment: found GUI for Selenium Grid http://www.codoid.com/products/view/2/30